# C++ Syntax error in header using class from another header

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

EDIT: My IDE was giving me a bad error message and because I was going through a major refactor, there were so many error messages on compile that I didn't read through them all, naively assuming that my IDE would know the problem.

**The problem was that the `Font` and `Text` headers referenced each other, and the compiler threw a syntax error on the `Text` token in the `Font` header. This was fixed by writing `class Text;` at the top of the `Font` header file, as @molbdnilo correctly answered.**

I apologize for my haste in ignoring compilation errors. I'd like to leave this as a message to future readers: `CLion 2021.1.1 Build #CL-211.7142.21` was unable to detect this error and semi-incorrectly highlighted the line mentioned below saying the constructor did not exist. The `Text` constructor could not be parsed because it circularly referenced the `Font` header.

---

The compiler is telling me that a constructor I have declared and defined does not match arguments that seem to match. My IDE recommends using the default constructor, but I have intentionally not defined one.

I have the following declarations and every member is implemented:

```
class Font {
private:
  static Shader* fontShader;
  std::map<char, Character> characters;
  unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
public:
  static void GLYPH_VAO_REGISTER();
  static Shader* getFontShader();
  Font(const std::string &name, int size);
  ~Font();
  Text *drawText(std::string text, float x, float y, float scale, glm::vec3 color);
};
```

```
class Text: public Renderable {
private:
  Font *font;
  const std::string &text;
public:
  Text(Font* font, const std::string &text);
};
```

When I try to create a new instance of both, I am able to create an instance of the `Font` class, but not the `Text` class:

```
Text* Font::drawText(std::string text, float x, float y, float scale, glm::vec3 color) {
  Text *target = new Text(this, text);
                     ^^^^ No matching constructor for initialization of 'Text'
  return target;
}
```

The definition of the `Text` constructor is:

```
Text::Text(Font *font, const std::string &text) : Renderable(
    ("text-" + text),
    true,
    GLYPH_VERTEX_COUNT,
    nullptr,
    GLYPH_INDEX_COUNT,
    nullptr,
    true,
    &Font::GLYPH_VAO_REGISTER,
    Font::getFontShader()), font(font), text(text) {}
```

My IDE shows the definition in the header file as existing, and I cannot figure out why the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the constructor. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: I think it's important to mention both of the class declarations are in different header files, and I think the problem is that neither is able to get the definition because they reference each other (I'd excluded functions which I now realize are crucial to reproducing the error). The error I got was a syntax error on the line `Font *font;` in the text.h file. Adding `class Font;` to the top seemed to stop the syntax error, but I'm unsure if it's actually solving the problem. I've added the function which references the `Text` class. I guess now I'm wondering why, even though the headers include each other, they are not able to see the declarations.

On compilation the errors are `text.h(17,8): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'` (line 17 being the `Font *font;` line) and `text.h(20,7): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Font'` (line 20 being the constructor).

Comment: On first glance it looks ok; the compiler will continue on and report what constructors it tried to use.  Can you include a few more lines of the compiler error messages.  If this report is just from the IDE (and not the compiler) try compiling and see if it goes away.

Comment: what is the full error message? Usually the available candidates gives you a clue

Comment: It wants a `const std::string &text`, you are giving it a `const char *`. It would have to allocate a temporary with questionable lifetime to satisfy that. It would probably be better to just pass that `std::string` by value. Or put it into an `std::string` on the caller's side.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue (building the code fails at the link stage, since I haven't added the implementation for the functions, but this is already past the point where the error you describe would occur. Post a [mcve].

Comment: ```text.h(17,8): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'``` Line 17 is ```Font *font;```. Would declaring ```class Font;``` above work to solve it? Doing that rids the error but I don't trust that it's using the right class.

Comment: @dratenik Passing `char const*` to a function requiring `std::string const&` seems pretty standard stuff to me. I don't see an issue with that. Of course there is an issue in this code related to this (storing a reference to the string object in the `Text` class instead of a copy) but that's unrelated to the choice of `std::string const&` as parameter. Since here the desired outcome seems to be not to duplicate the string memory, `std::string&&` would be a more appropriate choice of type than `std::string`

Comment: @CampbellCole - that's a completely different question from the question title.  Please edit your question and title to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: @CampbellCole The compiler needs to know about the full name of the `Font` class at the point of using it via pointer. If you don't If you don't trust yourself enough to get the namespace correct at that time the compiler would certainly complain at the time of using it. The issue here seems to be that `font.h` is included first which then includes `text.h` before there's any info about the `Font` class so the compiler at the point it sees the `Text` class doesn't know a thing about the `Font` class resulting in the compiler error. You do need to use a forward declaration here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem *because* the headers include each other, not despite it.
Remember that `#include` is a very primitive mechanism that literally only inserts the contents of a file in a certain place.

Take this simplified example:

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "B.h"

class A { B* b; };

#endif
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "A.h"

class B { A* a; };

#endif
```

Now, when compiling "A.h", it looks like this after preprocessing:

```
class B { A* a; };
class A { B* b; };
```

and `A` is unknown in that definition of `B`.
The `#include "A.h"` from "B.h" becomes nothing, since it is included inside the `A_H` include guard.

The same thing happens with "B.h", but in the other order.

The solution is to use forward declarations - since you're using pointers, you only need the class names, and you can just declare that they exist somewhere.
Then you include the headers in the source files that need them, and everything will be worked out by the compiler.

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class B;    
class A { B* b; };

#endif
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A;
class B { A* a; };

#endif
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

// Use A and B freely
```